# Data Source Connection in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a report using SSRS when the report is publish to the SSAS server (Different than DB Server), and I am trying to access the report I got strange error.

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source 'DD_BE'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS
```

then i go back to check the data source connection.
i set the credential is to use windows authentication (integrated).
[image]

here the connection in Data tool is fine 
[image]

every thing seems fine here then I go to check SSRS Manager to check Data Source.
[image]

And I changed the credential and I got different error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check** the option `Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source`.